# $this->request->is(array('put')) not working in cakephp framework

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, web-deployment

I have very strange problem with the following code,

```
$this->request->is(array('put'))
```

I have `Ubuntu` local server and I haven't got ant problems in my local server
but when I upload my local file on to a live server the following code,

```
$this->request->is(array('put'))
```

does not work.

What it means is that when I edit the form, it doesn't occur. My real problem is that no debugging tools such as `Debugkit` and debug and `error_log` are not reporting/logging any issues.

Comment: I think main issue in this problem come from $_POST. but i can't still understand why i can add item and i can't edit item.

Comment: this problem only happeing in special host and I finally prove that this problem realtead to online host and they change my host and fix problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP,  Contact the web server company you're hosting with... had similar issue but it was resolved from the server end, it has something to do with mod_securtiy.
I hope this helps

Comment: This is almost a year old question and the author has acknowledged that he fixed the issue. Please refrain from posting as an answer when it should be in the comments.